# SQL: How to set a custom MAX datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to convert a **non-temporal** table into a **temporal** one. I have two columns, an effective and expiration date.

My expiration dates are set to `2099-12-31 00:00:00` which SQL does not like (I guessing it wants `9999-12-31` etc).

A timestamp this high is unsupported by Pandas in **Python**, so using such a high date is impractical.

How can I tell SQL to change its max date to something lower / practical?

I get this error:

> ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME failed because table contains records where end of period is not equal to MAX datetime.

Comment: I find the valid to dates are more for internal processes, not for the application/presentation layer. If you want a lower value when querying, then use a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Usually people just leave an expiration date field NULL and handle it in code.

Comment: I think it's the opposite: you can't have dates that are later than the current date, change it to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find your query needed.

I explain 3 type of model we can use in temporal tables.

1. You can use migration and papulation scripts for convert table

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AWBuildVersion ADD
[TimeStart] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
[TimeEnd] DATETIME2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL CONSTRAINT,
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([TimeStart], [TimeEnd]);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.AWBuildVersion
SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.AWBuildVersion_History ) );
GO
```

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[dbo].[Temporal_Table_Demo] SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dbo].[Temporal_Table_Demo] ADD ID int IDENTITY (1,1);
ALTER TABLE dbo.[dbo].[Temporal_Table_Demo]
SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.[dbo].[Temporal_Table_Demo_History]));
```

[github link](https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/blob/master/Temporal%20table/Migration.sql)

2. Create one new and transfer, and if you create historical table with hidden column no need time version in main table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
    [EmployeeID]        int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [Name]          nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Position]      varchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Department]    varchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [Address]       nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL
  , [AnnualSalary]  decimal (10,2) NOT NULL
  , [ValidFrom]     datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , [ValidTo]       datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
GO

insert into dbo.Employee (
 [EmployeeID]   
,[Name]         
,[Position]     
,[Department]   
,[Address]      
,[AnnualSalary]     
)
Values (3,'Name','Pos','DEp','Add',2)

Update dbo.Employee set Name='AMIR' where EmployeeID=1
```

now you can see data in main table and history table

```
--Main table
Select * from dbo.Employee
-- history table
SELECT * FROM Employee
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME
    BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2021-12-01 00:00:00.0000000'
      WHERE EmployeeID = 1 ORDER BY ValidFrom;
```

[github](https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/blob/master/Temporal%20table/Temporal-Historycal.sql)

3. For other type you can set time, for adding versioning to non-temporal tables :

```
CREATE SCHEMA History;
GO

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy
    ADD
        SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN
            CONSTRAINT DF_SysStart DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()
      , SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN
            CONSTRAINT DF_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'), -- or '2099-12-31'
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);
GO

ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.InsurancePolicy));
```

[DocMicrosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#adding-versioning-to-non-temporal-tables)

Comment: This is great -- how might I ensure that my SysEndTime matches the `expirationDate` ( a column I have) so historical data is expired and not viewed as current with an expiration date of 9999-12-31

Comment: I did not understand exactly. I guess with join with history table you can ensure date time. here you can check all type of query for temporal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15